# TweenMax delayed call nad killtweens of

Tags: actionscript-3, gsap

Is anyone familiar with this Tween's delayed calls because I've been trying to get it work but I cant. I know how to call function with delay but I also want to remove that Tween for delayed call:

```
var speed:Number = player.getBasicSpeed();

            if (player.getSpeed() > speed)
            {
                TweenMax.killTweensOf(clearPowerup);
            }else {
                player.setSpeed(2.5);
                player.onPowerup("speedPowerup");
                TweenMax.delayedCall(5, clearPowerup, [player, speed]);
            }
```

So if player pick ups power-up and if this power-up still exists that `killTweensOf` should kill that delayed call for `clearPowerup` but it doesn't.

Thank you for your help

reagrds

Comment: I used different approach ...

Answer (score 0):

You need to use this line to kill delayed calls :

```
TweenMax.killDelayedCallsTo(clearPowerup);
```